# How to add emmet for css in Vs Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, emmet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBCYv.png)

i can't use emmet in css in Vs Code for some reason is it supported?
How to enable emmmet in css?

Comment: why would you want to enable emmet in CSS? this has nothing to do with CSS, this would result in invalid CSS.

Comment: It should be supported by default. Make sure you have emmet enabled by checking your builtin extensions. You can use the `@builtins` filter in your extensions search box: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_extensions-view-filter-and-commands Other than that you should make sure you are using it correctly. What are you doing that "doesn't work"?

Comment: i tried to use different comands in css it doesn't activate for some reason

Comment: What specifically is an example of a command you tried that did not work - what did you try, and what did you expect it to do? Also have you verified that it is enabled? (note that in my earlier comment the correct filter is `@builtin`, without the `s`).

Comment: @cloned they might be talking about this: https://docs.emmet.io/css-abbreviations/ . Monkey, is this what you're talking about?

Comment: @topsail non of the css commands work but html works fine  https://docs.emmet.io/cheat-sheet/ yeah i tried builtin it's enabled. I decided to reinstall vscode maybe it will help

Comment: i reinstalled it didin't helped

Comment: Can you describe *exactly* what you do when you say it doesn't work. We are still guessing about what you are typing and what you expect to happen after you type whatever it is you just typed.

Comment: By way of example: I can create a new `.css` file in VSCode, and on the first line type `.foo { m:0` followed by `tab` - both the autocomplete for the brace pair and the emmet insertion of `margin: 0` works fine. The result here  is `.foo {margin: 0;}`

Comment: @topsail  it started to work maybe reinstalation helped

Answer (score 0):

add this in JSON settings:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "CSS": "css",

}
```

Comment: it didn't helped